# Background Image 100% Not Working In Instances

Tags: php, html, css

This works for my homepage to make a image fit my background.

```
<body>
<div style="height:100%; background-image:url(location.png); background-size:cover;">
<?php include("homebuttons.php");?>
</div>
</body>
```

But doesn't seem to want to work in this one

```
<body>
<div style="height:100%; background-image:url(location.png); background-size:cover;">
<div class="navbar">
<?php include("navbar.php"); ?>
</div>
<div id="content">
<?php include("pages/" . $_POST["var"] . ".php"); ?>
</div></div>
</body>
```

I've tried positioning the DIV in different location, but still nothing. All I need is a background for certain page. I plan on using this code after I finish.

```
<div style="height:100%; background-image:url(<?php echo $_POST["var"] ?>.jpg); background-size:cover;">
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the style="height:100%; in you div, when you define height:100% this 100% refers to the element parent size and not the viewport size. this works only for the width, you'll need the set the min-height with a px size to get this working.

Comment: or javascript i guess

Comment: even when i set the the min-height to 100% it doesn't work. I just want that image to fill up the background and be determined off of their brewer size.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason when you have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

in the document this 100% fit will not work. Weird.